# How do I count the number of comments entered made on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that I currently can tell how many answers from the various dropdown menus have been selected. Now I want to be able to count the comments made that are inside the textarea tag. I have a js fiddle for what I basically have.

https://jsfiddle.net/josephmckenzie/Lr1evv3v/3/

When you click the comment link it will open an accordion with a comment box under the current dropdown, and once entered they go on to next question. They should both count up (dropdown counter works already), and if a comment is entered in conjunction with the menu selection, the comment counter should count up as well.

```
 <div class="QuestionsAnswered">
summary<br>
Total  = <span class="cnt-total">0</span> <br>
</div>

<select name="firstone">
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="na">N/A</option>
</select>   

<div class="accordion">Comment</div>
   <div class="panel">
      <textarea name="comment<%=index%>" rows="4" cols="15"></textarea>
   </div>


<select name="secondone">
   <option value="">Choose One</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="na">N/A</option>
</select>
```

the js

```
$('select').change(function() {
// get all selects
var allSelects = $('select')
var total = 0;

// for each select increase count
$.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
    // increase count
    if($(s).val() == 'Yes' ) { total++; }
    if($(s).val() == 'No') { total++; }
    if($(s).val() == 'na') { total++; }
});

$('.cnt-total').text(total);

 });

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
};
```

I've tried changing the select to text area and the .val != to a blank string and a few other things but alas I come to you Stack

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you used jQuery for the `select` change but not for the comment click?

Comment: Just because you use Ruby somewhere in your app doesn't make the question a Ruby question. If you used Ruby in the example code it'd be pertinent, but as is it's not and acts as a distraction.

Comment: @jwatts1980 nope , didnt realize i hadnt that could be an issue , as the drop downs dont count with out jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure 'total' is a global variable, so take it out of your $(.'select').change(function()) (https://jsfiddle.net/Lr1evv3v/7/).

```
$("#the_answer").on("blur", function(){
 $(this).val() ? total++ : total--;
 $('.cnt-total').text(total); //to update the total text
});
```

Comment: Im really linking this one but after you make the first drop down selection it counts the next one up two, Ill try on my own but maybe you can help me fix that issue?

Comment: Well yeah, "$.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {" is iterating over ALL dropdowns every time one of the dropdown values changes; so if a value has already been selected in of the the dropdowns, that gets taken into calculation as well.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense  but what i meant was I choose yes the first one count is 1 then enter a comment count is 2 then when i go to the second drop down it jumps to 4

Comment: Yes, my previous response exactly explains why that is.

Comment: ok i understand what you mean now, so how could we go about just adding one to the total rather than adding everything thats already been filled in plus that , I have it counting and only adding one for all 20 + questions on my site now i wanna do the same thing with the comments

Comment: It can be as simple as: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr1evv3v/21/ You really don't have a need for that "$.each()" there. Lastly, if this answers your question, please mark it as so!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept this answer ,and figure out the last thing on my own, which is say you select yes then comment select the next drop down then go back and change your answer on the first one it counts up again, but thank you for getting to here